# Reference dynamic to groovy closure

Tags: grails, groovy, closures

I have to do a refactoring in an advanced search method with 500 lines.  I split this method using closures in small parts, and now I have a lot of closures but I want to invoke them dynamically.

For example:

```
def listCriteria={ ... }
def textCriteria={ ... }
def booleanCriteria={ ... }

criteria.listDistinct {
    criteries.eachWithIndex { crit, i->
        def criteriaType="${crit.type}Criteria"
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you really nee closures or could you also use pure methods?

Comment: I need to build a big criteria, now this method has 500 line, and I don;t want to rewrite it with hql because the risk is high

Answer (score 0):

Using methods you could dynamically call this methods from a string like this:

```
def listCriteria() {"list"}
def textCriteria() {"text"}

def string1 = "list"
def string2 = "text"

assert "${string1}Criteria"() == "list"
assert "${string2}Criteria"() == "text"
```

*Edit:*

I don't know an elegant way to get a dynamic reference to a closure.

You could use the `properties` property of your controller class to find all closures and invoke them.

```
def allClosures = this.properties.findAll{Closure.isAssignableFrom(it.value.getClass())}

def callCriteriaClosureByName(name) {
    def criteriaClosure = allClosures.find{it.key == "${name}Criteria"}.value
    if(criteriaClosure)
        criteriaClosure()
}
```

Not that nice - but should work.

Comment: I agree with you, but if i want to delegate it to another closure, how  I can do that, because I'm using and inner closures?

Answer (score 0):

Closures are good for scoping. What about using a map?

```
class Criteria {
  def listDistinct(closure) {
    closure()
  }
}


closures = [ 
  listCriteria : { "list" },
  textCriteria : { "text" },
  booleanCriteria : { "boolean" }
]


def criteries = ["list", "text", "boolean"]
def criteria = new Criteria()

criteria.listDistinct {
    criteries.eachWithIndex { crit, index ->
        def criteriaType=closures["${crit}Criteria"]
        assert criteriaType instanceof Closure
    }
}
```